# Issue With Passing FormData in Vue.js to Netlify Lambda via POST, and Then to CF7 WordPress Endpoint

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, form-data, netlify

I'm not knowledgeable enough to know all the ins and outs of formatting data for http requests. I'm trying to send FormData from a vue.js app into a netlify serverless function (lambda) and then pass that FormData along to my Contact Form 7 WordPress plugin REST API.

I managed to get my FormData passed to my lambda using JSON.stringify, and when I JSON.parse the data seems to be intact. I then used form-data in node to build a new FormData object to pass.

I noticed however that I'm unable to console.log it's contents using the client-side method of:

```
// I get values is not a function
    for (var value of formData.values()) {
        console.log('>> VALUE = ',value);
     }

// I get entries is not a function
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
```

This is a red flag to me, telling me that FormData in node might not be handled the same as FormData in my vue.js code..

When I try to hit my Contact Form 7 endpoint with the data, I get an error in my response saying that one or more of my fields are in error, even though it seems to look ok to me, so something is up, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to determine what the solution is.

My gut is telling me that there's something I need to do still, to format the data, or send the data in a way that Contact Form 7 is expecting..

Earlier in my project history, when I ran an axios.post in vue.js (not using netlify lambda) it worked and my contact form emails were sending, so I know I'm hitting the right endpoint with the right codes/data.

Here is all the relevant code I'm using for this project:

```
// --------------------------------------------
// in my vue.js component:
// --------------------------------------------

this.bodyFormData = new FormData()
this.bodyFormData.append( 'your-name', this.value_name )
this.bodyFormData.append( 'tel-725', this.value_phone )
this.bodyFormData.append( 'your-email', this.value_email )
this.bodyFormData.append( 'your-subject', this.value_subject )
this.bodyFormData.append( 'your-message', this.value_message )

// (...)

let theFormData = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(this.bodyFormData))
Vue.prototype.$http.post('/.netlify/functions/myfunction',{token:token, formData:theFormData})

// --------------------------------------------
// in my netlify serverless lambda function myfunction.js :
// --------------------------------------------

const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const AUTH_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.####.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/'
const FORM_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.####.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1217/feedback'
const captchaThreshhold = 0.5

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    const eventBody = JSON.parse(event.body)
    const captchaToken = eventBody.token
    const stringFormData = eventBody.formData

    let parsedFormData = JSON.parse(stringFormData);

    console.log('>> parsedFOrmData ', parsedFormData) //logs a JSON object with correct key/value pairs

    // logs:
    // >> parsedFOrmData  {
    //     'your-name': 'Jon Doe',
    //     'tel-725': '(555) 555-5555',
    //     'your-email': 'jon@doe.com',
    //     'your-subject': 'Suuuuubject',
    //     'your-message': 'Meeeeesage!'
    //   }

    let formData = new FormData();

    for ( var key in parsedFormData ) {
        formData.append(key, parsedFormData[key])
    }

    // I get values is not a function
    for (var value of formData.values()) {
        console.log('>> VALUE = ',value);
     }

    // I get entries is not a function
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    }

    // (...)

    axios.post(FORM_API_ENDPOINT, {formData}, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${res.data.token}`,
            // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset="utf-8"', //do I need this?
        }
    })
    .then( res => {
        console.log('>> response came back from the Form endpoint : ',res)
    })

    // the res.data I get back form WordPress Contact Form 7 Plugin Endpoint:

    data: {
        into: '#',
        status: 'validation_failed',
        message: 'One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.',
        posted_data_hash: '',
        invalid_fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
      }

    //res.config data logs as this:
                
        {"formData":{"_overheadLength":545,"_valueLength":54,"_valuesToMeasure":[],"writable":false,"readable":true,"dataSize":0,"maxDataSize":2097152,"pauseStreams":true,"_released":false,"_streams":["----------------------------611729353459041078880042\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"your-name\\"\\r\\n\\r\\n","Jon Doe",null,"----------------------------611729353459041078880042\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"tel-725\\"\\r\\n\\r\\n","(555) 555-5555",null,"----------------------------611729353459041078880042\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"your-email\\"\\r\\n\\r\\n","jon@doe.com",null,"----------------------------611729353459041078880042\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"your-subject\\"\\r\\n\\r\\n","Suuuuubject",null,"----------------------------611729353459041078880042\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"your-message\\"\\r\\n\\r\\n","Meeeeesage!",null],"_currentStream":null,"_insideLoop":false,"_pendingNext":false,"_boundary":"--------------------------611729353459041078880042"}}
```

If you know what the problem is.. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong! Thank you! :)

Comment: In your node function you do axios.post, there you could send parsedFormData instead of { formData }

Comment: Hi Joshua. I tried sending parsedFormData with and without curly brackets, I also tried sending the stringify version. They all return the same error. I had a similar issue when I was doing it from my vue.js app, but it was solved by formatting my data as FormData, so I think CF7 is expecting FormData instead of a JSON object.

Comment: Alright, I think you are right about CF7 wanting FormData instead of a json object. Tell axios to send as form-data by adding the Content-type: multipart/form-data header and then send formData without the curley brackets > axios.post(FORM_API_ENDPOINT, formData, { headers: { Authorization: ..., ContentType: 'multipart/form-data' } });

Comment: I tried that too.. still seems to be responding with the same error.. Hmmmm... I'm running out of ideas.. maybe I'll try a Fetch request instead of axios? I thought I saw somewhere that axios may have issues with node.js or something. I'm kind of just shooting in the dark now lol.

Comment: The fact that I can't console log my FormData using formData.entries() makes me think the FormData itself is the issue.. like there's a special way to encode it in Node or something... I dunno..

Comment: I solved it! It had to do with the FormData object headers needing to be passed with the data. I had no idea until I randomly stumbled on the code view in Postman. (see code below)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue... it seems that the FormData headers need to be passed along with the data.. I randomly stumbled across the answer while messing around with Postman and found the answer buried in the Node.js code view.

For those of you who have the same issue.. see below:

```
axios.post(FORM_API_ENDPOINT, formData, {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${res.data.token}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset="utf-8"',
                        ...formData.getHeaders() // <--- THIS LINE HERE
                    }
                })
```